# loop is running 5 times but asking for input only 2 times

Tags: c, loops, input

This is my code, here I am taking **char** input each time loop runs.

I am giving 5 inputs but it is only responding to 2 of them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while (t--)
    {
        char c;
        scanf("%c",&c);
        if(c =='b' || c== 'B')
            printf("BattleShip\n");
        else if(c=='c' || c=='C')
            printf("Cruiser\n");
        else if(c == 'd' || c=='D')
            printf("Destroyer\n");
        else if(c=='f' || c=='F')
            printf("Frigate\n");
    }
}
```

```
Input:
5 
b f c b f

Output:
BattleShip
Frigate
```

Comment: What is the input you receive in `c`? Output its integer value (`printf("%d\n", (int)c);`), just to avoid the problem that you can't see a space or linebreak. BTW, as a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask] (though your question does *not* have typical beginners' mistakes in it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your "scanf"-function in the loop. The char %c identifier reads \n as input if you use:
`scanf("%c", &c)`
If you write it as follows:
`scanf(" %c", &c)`
your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `scanf("%c", &c)` only reads one character, but the input has space between letters and space is also an ascii character. The spaces are causing the problem, not the newline(\n) after `5`.
you can use `scanf(" %c", &c)`, with a space before `%c`, this way scanf
ignores white-space characters like space and newline, no matter how
many they are. this solution works even if you put many spaces
between your inputs.

Answer (score -1):

there is no problem in your code
Try any other compiler.
Sometimes this type of issue resolve after changing the compiler

Comment: If that works, it seems to be a good indication for undefined behaviour which is the opposite of "no problem in the code".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).